# Message not working after run ajax in magento 2 ( save form_ui in backend )

Tags: jquery, magento, magento2

Please help me! i'm writing form save stock taking in magento 2, after save -> message not working , if reload page it's work. Thanks you so much

**FUNCTION EXECUTE IN MY CONTROLLER**

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$sku = $data['sku'];
$qty = $data['qty'];
try {
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $productId = $this->product->getIdBySku($sku);
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $stockItem = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($product->getSku());
            $stockItem->setQty($qty);
            $stockItem->save();
            //echo "ok ".$sku;

            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('All good'));

        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            //echo "khong co ".$sku;
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This is bad'));
        }
$response = $this->resultFactory
            ->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
            ->setData([
                'sku' => $sku,
                'qty' => $qty
            ]);
        return $response;
```

**MY JQUERY**

```
require(['jquery','jquery/ui'],function($){
$("#button-unique-identifier-here").click(function(){
    var sku = $("input[name$='general[sku]']").val();
    var stocktaking = $("input[name$='general[stocktaking]']").val();
    url = '/admin/stocktaking/index/save';
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type : 'post',
        data: {sku: sku,qty: stocktaking},
        success: function($response){
                alert("ss");
                console.log($response);
        }
    });
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The addSuccessMessage() and addErrorMessage() functions are working on page reload in Magento. So you need to do some customization to display message after ajax response. Send a JSON response from your controller like follows:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$sku = $data['sku'];
$qty = $data['qty'];
$response = [];
try {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productId = $this->product->getIdBySku($sku);
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
    $stockItem = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($product->getSku());
    $stockItem->setQty($qty);
    $stockItem->save();

    $response = ['error' => false, 'message' => __('All good')];
}
catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    $response = ['error' => true, 'message' => __('This is bad')];
}

echo json_encode($response); // return response to ajax call in js file
```

According to response variable print your message as follows:
Suppose you want to print message in `<div id="printmessage">`:

```
require(['jquery','jquery/ui'],function($){
    $("#button-unique-identifier-here").click(function(){
        var sku = $("input[name$='general[sku]']").val();
        var stocktaking = $("input[name$='general[stocktaking]']").val();
        url = '/admin/stocktaking/index/save';
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type : 'post',
            data: {sku: sku,qty: stocktaking},
            success: function($response) {
                var res = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response));
                var responseText = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                if (responseText.error === true) {
                    $("#printmessage").addClass("error");
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    $("#printmessage").addClass("success");
                }
                $("#printmessage").html(responseText.message);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Run following command:

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

I hope this may helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see exactly where your problem is, but you can simplify your code a little and load the stockItem directly by the given sku. The following code works for me, if I call it for example directly by URL with parameters sku and qty set:

```
$data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$sku = $data['sku'];
$qty = $data['qty'];

try {
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $stockItem = $this->_stockRegistry->getStockItemBySku($sku);
    $stockItem->setQty($qty);
    $stockItem->save();
    //echo "ok ".$sku;

    $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('All good'));

} catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
    //echo "khong co ".$sku;
    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('This is bad'));
}
$response = $this->resultFactory
            ->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON)
            ->setData([
                'sku' => $sku,
                'qty' => $qty
            ]);
return $response;
```

Most likely the problem is related to your JSON return, but I'm not the expert for that :-)